# Convert JsonArray to Model using wrapper class

Tags: c#, json

I want to deserialize a jsonarray into a list of objects.

JSON string is here:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    customer: "Joe Black",
    items: {
        id: 1,
        description: "One",
        unit_price: 1.00,
        quantity: 1
    }
},{
    id: 2,
    customer: "Joe",
    items: {
        id: 2,
        description: "two",
        unit_price: 1.00,
        quantity: 4
    }
}]
```

and

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<rootClass>>(jsonString)
```

UPDATE: Here are my classes

```
public class customer { 
    public int id {get; set;} 
    public string customer {get; set;} 
    public Item item {get; set;} 
} 

public class Item { 
    public string id {get; set;} 
    public string description {get; set;} 
    public int unit_price {get; set;} 
    public int quantity {get; set;} 
}
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @Juhana it seems that the author uses C#

Comment: @Juhana i am using c#

Comment: @markbernard It's not my own json.

Comment: I need to convert json string into list<class> for the json

Comment: @user2011138 It's your own code correct? What have you tried to get it working?

Comment: @markbernard While using json deserialization the value doesn't assigined to the list.

Comment: What specifically is the error? And why haven't you shown the definition for `rootClass` in your question?

Comment: I am not getting any Error but value not assigned.                                                                               public class customer
{
public int id{get;set;}
public string customer {get;set;}
public Item item{get;set;}

}

public class Item
{
public string id{get;set;}
public string description: {get;set;}
public int unit_price {get;set;}
public int quantity {get;set;}
}                                                                                                                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<customer>>(jsonString)

Answer (score 1):

Using a tool like http://jsonutils.com/ you can paste in your JSON and it will generate what your classes would look like (provided that the JSON is valid).

Parsing the JSON you provided yielded the following

```
public class Items
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public double unit_price { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}

public class rootClass
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string customer { get; set; }
    public Items items { get; set; }
}
```

which differs from your class definitions.

Specifically the `Item` class and the `item` property in your `customer` class.

You need to review the data and make sure that it matches your class structure.

Comment: I am getting items  as null

Comment: In the comment you posted with your class I noticed that you have the property as `item` (singular) not `items` (plural) which does not match your JSON

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ConsoleApplication.rootClass' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: The json example you provided and your classes don't match up.